# MacBookPro 11,5 - How do I get brightness control?

Tags: laptop, brightness, mac, macbook-pro, backlight

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and Gnome
[image]

```
# sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
MacBookPro11,5
```

My problem:

- brightness keys (fn + f1, fn + f2) don't change brightness.
- there is no brightness slider under the gnome power settings (just keyboard backlight brightness)
  [image]
- the only way I seem to be able to change the brightness is to edit `/sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness` and then restart.
- setting `--brightness` through `xrandr` is just contrast, and doesn't change the backlight intensity. (this is probably intended functionality of `xrandr` but isn't how I / anyone should want to adjust brightness)

my display:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2880 x 1800, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 2880x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   2880x1800     59.99*+
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     59.96  
   1600x1200     59.87  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1280x854      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1152x768      59.78  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   848x480       59.66  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x480       59.38  
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

my `/etc/default/grub` file

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
```

#

```
 /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
# Changed in order to get backlight control working
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I've also tried `acpi_backlight=native` to no avail.

I ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted after all changes to this file.

My backlight folder has two directories:

- radeon_bl0/
- gmux_backlight/ <- as far as I can tell, this isn't used.

How do I debug this further, and get my backlight controls working?

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess here; on the previous version (macbookpro 11.3) you had to run

```
setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0
```

maybe it's the same on this one?

Comment: I just blindly ran that in the terminal (bad, I know), and the brightness keys still don't work (Also, still no brightness slider in power options) . Does this require a restart or anything?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Confirmation: that doesn't work on a MBP 2015 either.

Answer (score 1):

this is a kernel problem. You need to patch and rebuild the kernel to fix this problem.

I have created a blog post about fixing it for Fedora. There are links to two patches that you need to apply: http://blog.samalik.com/fedora-24-on-macbook-pro-114-and-115-suspend-and-brightness-fix/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see that post is for Fedora. Do those commands work on Ubuntu/Debian?

Comment: The Fedora commands and Debian commands probably vary vastly. Please add some useful information for Ubuntu, and use your Fedora-based blog post as reference.

Comment: I built a kernel with the patches found here https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-macbook/, specifically the `apple-gmux.patch`, and backlight adjustment now works in GNOME Shell. xbacklight still doesn't work though.

Comment: Adam's blog links to the solution for this. You can make a shell script from comment 37: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105051#c37 (make sure there are tabs in front of the make commands for the Makefile, not spaces). Then just chmod and run with sudo.